# NSTimer Spawning Function

Tags: swift, nstimer

I have to following code:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) { // Only run if its a "contact"


    // ENDING
    var contactBody1: SKPhysicsBody
    var contactBody2: SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        contactBody1 = contact.bodyA
        contactBody2 = contact.bodyB

    } else {

        contactBody2 = contact.bodyB
        contactBody1 = contact.bodyA
    }

    if ((contactBody1.categoryBitMask == 2) && (contactBody2.categoryBitMask == 1)) {

       contactBody2.node!.removeFromParent()

        //p1.fillColor = SKColor.greenColor()
        //p1.strokeColor = SKColor.greenColor()

    }}
```

This code is running a collision test. When object A and B collide I want to change the colour of "p1".

Next I have this code.

```
var moveBlockLine1 = SKAction.moveByX(-self.frame.size.width * 2, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.width / 60))


var p1 = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
p1.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
p1.strokeColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
p1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
p1.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + self.frame.size.width / 2 + 50, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)) //
p1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false // Will not be affected by gravity
p1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false // Stops the image moving if its hit by a ball.
p1.physicsBody?.friction = 0
p1.alpha = 1
```

This code is spawning blocks from right to left across the screen. My problem is, that in order for the 1st code to work, I need to move "var p1 = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))" to a different place because at the moment, swift cannot identify "p1" in the collision code.

When I move the "var p1" part, the collision code works, because now p1 can be identified, however, the second part of code, the spawning, makes the app crash because now swift cannot spawn an object that is has already spawned before. The spawning code is running off an NSTimer.

Anyway around this? Thanks :)

Comment: Please show us some code example. It will make easier to help you.

Comment: var moveBlockLine1 = SKAction.moveByX(-self.frame.size.width * 2, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.width / 60))

    var p1 = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)) So I am running this code to create a block with an NSTImer interval. I want to move the "Var p1" part outside of this area of code, because I need to put it at the start of the code so a collision action can run on "p1"

Comment: However if I move the "var p1" part under class "Level1: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {" so that the collision action will run and work, then the NSTimer cannot properly spawn a node and keep crashing. But I NEED "var p1" to be under the SKScene...  thanks :)

Comment: The code will be more readable if you edit your original question and add it there. Also, following the hints in [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you will help you to get more and better replies.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for your advice Mario :)